# ODBC select statement to get a boolean

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ado.net, odbc

I'm trying to check whether a Username and Password exist in my MySQL database and if so I need to return true, otherwise false. This is what I have atm:

```
myconn.Open()

Dim selectSQL As String = "SELECT * 
                             FROM member 
                            WHERE Username = " & objMember.Username & " 
                              AND Password= " & objMember.Password
Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand(selectSQL, myconn)

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

If cmd.Parameters.Count = 1 Then
    Return True
Else
    Return False
End If

myconn.Close()
myconn.Dispose()
```

All I get is 0, even though the Username and Password exist! Or perhaps I'm wrong with my coding?

---

### SOLUTION

```
myconn.Open()

Dim count As Integer = 0

Dim selectSQL As String = "SELECT COUNT(*)
                             FROM member 
                            WHERE Username = ? 
                              AND Password= ?"
Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand(selectSQL, myconn)

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LidLoginnaam", objLid.LidLoginnaam)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LidWachtwoord", objLid.LidWachtwoord)

count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())

If count = 1 Then
    Return True
Else
    Return False
End If

myconn.Close()
myconn.Dispose()
```

Comment: Hi Tom. Please see the distinction between command execution methods first here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand(v=vs.71).aspx. Don't use string concatenation to build your SQL query, use parameters instead : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcparameter.aspx. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use string concatenation to build your SQL queries, use parameters instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcparameter.aspx

```
Dim count as Integer = 0

Try
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM member WHERE Username = @username AND Password = @password"
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", objMember.Username)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", objMember.Password)
    count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
End Try

Return (count > 0)
```

If you don't use the data retrieved from your query, then just use **ExecuteScalar** to get the number of records that matched your Username and Password.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbccommand.executescalar.aspx

This basically returns TRUE if count > 0 (meaning there is a record that matched the Username and Password).

Also check out the distinction between the different command execution methods here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand(v=vs.71).aspx. You are using **ExecuteNonQuery** for retrieving records which is incorrect for this purpose.

Hope this helps.

Comment: OMG thanks! I used your scalar and changed it slightly. Check my post.

Comment: Hi Tom, just set breakpoints and follow the execution line-by-line to debug it.

Comment: Wasn't really able to do it using breakpoints. Btw, do you know a thing or two about SQLinjection? I only know how to cover it in PHP.

Comment: @Tom: Are you sure this is not working? I'm not using an IDE now but I'm pretty sure this is gonna work. Oh well...

Comment: @Tom: You immediately avoid the risk of SQLInjection when using parameters. When using strings to build queries, it's pretty easy to "inject" malicious commands most common is using comments. But parameters ultimately escapes those "evil" characters so SQLInjection is avoided.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the [SQL Injection risks](http://xkcd.com/327/), strings in SQL need to be within single quotes:

```
Dim selectSQL As String = "SELECT m.* 
                             FROM MEMBER m
                            WHERE m.username = '" & objMember.Username & "'
                              AND m.password = '" & objMember.Password & "' "
```

From a performance perspective, if you aren't interested in the contents of the query then don't return more information than you need to:

```
Dim selectSQL As String = "SELECT 1
                             FROM MEMBER m
                            WHERE m.username = '" & objMember.Username & "'
                              AND m.password = '" & objMember.Password & "' "
```

The query will be faster -- if any of the `MEMBER` columns are BLOB, you could be waiting for a while.

Comment: Is there a way to cover the SQL injection risks? Okay thanks, I'll change it!

Comment: @Tom: Sorry - I don't know VB.NET enough to make a recommendation.

Comment: any clues on how I can check to see if the value exists?

Comment: @Tom: Look for info on "parameterized queries".  Sorry - "check if the value exists"?  Your logic doesn't look at the result, just whether it has one as I understand it.

Comment: Well I want it to look if he can find a row with the Username and Password, ifso I need something to check this? I thought using cmd.Parameters.Count would work?

Comment: @Tom: Like I said, VB isn't my strong suit - check the documentation.  You could try printing out the query string after the values have been supplied, and run the query in MySQL to make sure it's valid & returning valid results.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing the single quotation in the query:

```
Dim selectSQL As String = "SELECT * 
                             FROM member 
                            WHERE Username = '" & objMember.Username & "' 
                              AND Password= '" & objMember.Password & "'"
```

Comment: Don't use strings to build your queries since it's a very error-prone method not to mention the security risks. Use parameters instead, it's safer and easier way to do it.

Comment: You don't have also to check for the parameters count. This is not the right thing to check for. You need to use cmd.ExecuteReader that returns data reader. Then loop through the records using reader.Read() method to fetch the returned rows. Please check a sample here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/979byfca.aspx

Comment: @mohadmmedn: I think Tom just wants this to authenticate Username and Password, doesn't necessarily need the data. So it's better to use ExectureScaler for this. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

OdbcCommand's Parameter property is used for accessing the collection of parameters to be used when executing a query ([more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcparametercollection.aspx)). It doesn't help you find out how many rows are contained in the query's result set.

If your only concern is determining whether or not the requested member is in the database, change the start of your query to `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM....`. This revised query will return a single value indicating how many records match your query's criteria.

Execute this query by calling [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbccommand.executescalar.aspx). The return value of this method will be the value returned by the above query--the number of rows matching your query's criteria. If the value equals zero, you know that no matching member exists in the database. Use this value instead of "cmd.Parameters.Count" in your "if" statement.

Hope this helps,
Ben

Comment: thanks, you're just a tad late with your solution :P check my revised post :P