# Apostrophe in sql string how can I remove

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I need some help. I use a combo box to create a sql query. Here is the query string

```
SQlstr = "UPDATE maindata SET " _
            & "?theoption1 = ?therec1 " _
            & "WHERE acct = ?theaccount AND clientnumber=?theclient;"
```

?theoption1 is a field name but it comes out with an apostrophe like 'xxxxx' , and this causes an error. How do I get around this. I cant use Replace because I am using parameters.
Thanks for any help I can get.

Comment: This code is inherently unsafe and subject to sql injection.

Comment: See also [Bobby-Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) for an explanation of sql injection and how to fix it.

Comment: I thought parameterized queries would avoid sql injection?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6005286